# Wubi installation won't start

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I've just installed ubuntu 11.10 via wubi. Everything was going ok, but all the sudden it started going slow, freezing during file operations and then complete freeze. I restarted the PC an now it wont start in ubuntu.

After I select ubuntu from the boot screen, the screen goes purple like it's going to start, but stays that way, no mouse, no keybord.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

P.S: i'm running windows 7, in case it matters.

Comment: Did you try to run the LiveCD from the Ubuntu CD. Just to know if it is something related to the Windows system with Ubuntu or the Hardware and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi doesn't like hard resets. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>SysRq</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to [safely reboot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#.E2.80.9CREISUB.E2.80.9D_.E2.80.93_safe_reboot).

In general, I'd advise:

1. Boot windows and run `chkdsk /f` on the 'drive' containing Ubuntu. If it's the `C:\` 'drive' you'll have to reboot to let it complete.
2. Try booting again. If it hangs, then safely reboot, and retry editing the first grub menu entry pressing <kbd>E</kbd>, remove the text `quiet splash`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to boot, and then see where it is hanging.
3. You may have to boot a live CD and `fsck` the virtual disk `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`, but first see whether you can find out some more details about the problem.

If you find any information that you think will help, please update your question with the details, and I'll update this answer if there is anything to add. Also please report your graphics card and whether you've installed any custom drivers.